# Does such a tensor exist?

Tags: normed-spaces, tensors, spectral-theory

let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ and define $S=AA^\dagger$. The (square of the) operator/spectral norm of $A$ can be written as
$$
\sigma_0^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{u^TS^{n+1}u}{u^TS^nu}
$$
where $u$ is any vector that is not orthogonal to the first left singular vector of $A$ (first as in corresponding to the largest singular value of $A$).

*Question*: can I make a tensor $\Gamma_n$ $=$ "$\frac{S^{n+1}}{S^n}$" (please notice the quotation marks) such that $$\sigma_0^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Gamma_n uuuu$$
where by $\Gamma_n uuuu$ we mean the contraction $\sum_{ijkl}(\Gamma_n)_{ijlk}u_iu_ju_ku_l$?

Comment: I don't think your first statement is true. For example if $A=\begin{pmatrix}i&-i\\-i&i\end{pmatrix}$ then $S=\begin{pmatrix}2&-2\\-2&2\end{pmatrix}$ and $u^TS^nu=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: You are correct, in fact $u$ can be any vector as long as it is not orthogonal to the first left singular vector of $A$, and in your example it is (and your $A$ is rank-1, which makes it even more dramatically wrong!). I fixed the statement.